# Image is not showing as src attribute but works as open in new tab

Tags: php, image, browser, cross-browser

In my angular app (hosted on `http://localhost:4200`) I have `img` tag that is fetching image from `api` server using `php`. 
That image is not showing using `<img src="http://api.path.local/image.jpg">` but when in console I click `open in new tab` on `src` attribute everything is ok.

Image path is pointing to `php` script:

```php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
echo readfile($filepath); // also tried echo file_get_contents($filepath);
exit;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the browser's debugging tools, is the HTTP request for the image made when the page is loaded?  What is the server's response?

Comment: Request is present: ```HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 26 May 2020 12:55:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.4.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.3
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
Content-Length: 3469
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8```

Comment: The server's response includes `Content-Type: text/html`?  Sounds like there's something different about that request vs. the one that successfully loads the image.  What's in the response body?

Comment: There is nothing in body.  When pasting imager path directly in browser content-type is `image/jpeg`

Comment: You may need to capture both of those requests in the debugging tools and go through each detail to see in what way they differ.  It's also worth adding some debugging output to the PHP script to see what might be going on there and why it's not returning the file.  There's PHP code not shown here, and the problem could very well be in that code.